# If Statement not evaluating as expected. Am I setting up my variables incorrectly?

Tags: bash, shell, bash-scripting

I am trying to create a command that will allow me to check websites for specific words. I used \ at the end of the line to wrap it to the next, (not sure if I used those correctly here) these characters are not in my script.

```
check=$(lynx -source $1 | grep -i $2)
if [[ $check == *"$2"* ]]

then
  /usr/local/bin/sendemail -o tls=yes -f ***@gmail.com -t\
  trigger@recipe.ifttt.com -s smtp.gmail.com:587 -xu ***@gmail.com -xp *** -u\
  $1 -m "contains the word " $2 ".";

else
  /usr/local/bin/sendemail -o tls=yes -f ***@gmail.com -t\
  trigger@recipe.ifttt.com -s smtp.gmail.com:587 -xu ***@gmail.com -xp *** -u\
  $1 -m "does not contain the word " $2 ".";

fi
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `grep` to check the output case-insensitively, then you're checking grep's output using a case-sensitive glob pattern.

Do this instead:

```
if lynx -source "$1" | grep -qi "$2"; then
    msg="contains the word '$2'."
else
    msg="does not contain the word '$2'."
fi

/usr/local/bin/sendemail -o tls=yes -f ***@gmail.com -t trigger@recipe.ifttt.com -s smtp.gmail.com:587 -xu ***@gmail.com -xp *** -u "$1" -m "$msg"
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks for the help. Sounds like i have gobs of glob pattern research to do.

Answer (score 0):

#### If Statement not evaluating as expected.

Checking your script with [ShellCheck](http://www.shellcheck.net/) (finds bugs in your shell scripts.) gives the following suggestions:

```
$ shellcheck myscript

Line 1:
check=$(lynx -source $1 | grep -i $2)
                     ^-- SC2086: Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting.
                                  ^-- SC2086: Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting.

Line 5:
  /usr/local/bin/sendemail -o tls=yes -f ***@gmail.com -t\
                                         ^-- SC2035: Use ./*glob* or -- *glob* so names with dashes won't become options.

Line 6:
  trigger@recipe.ifttt.com -s smtp.gmail.com:587 -xu ***@gmail.com -xp *** -u\
                                                     ^-- SC2035: Use ./*glob* or -- *glob* so names with dashes won't become options.
                                                                       ^-- SC2035: Use ./*glob* or -- *glob* so names with dashes won't become options.

Line 7:
  $1 -m "contains the word " $2 ".";
  ^-- SC2086: Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting.
                             ^-- SC2086: Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting.

Line 10:
  /usr/local/bin/sendemail -o tls=yes -f ***@gmail.com -t\
                                         ^-- SC2035: Use ./*glob* or -- *glob* so names with dashes won't become options.

Line 11:
  trigger@recipe.ifttt.com -s smtp.gmail.com:587 -xu ***@gmail.com -xp *** -u\
                                                     ^-- SC2035: Use ./*glob* or -- *glob* so names with dashes won't become options.
                                                                       ^-- SC2035: Use ./*glob* or -- *glob* so names with dashes won't become options.

Line 12:
  $1 -m "does not contain the word " $2 ".";
  ^-- SC2086: Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting.
                                     ^-- SC2086: Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting.

$
```

See the following links for explanation of the suggestions:

- https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2086
- https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2035

Comment: Thanks for the feedback David! I'm new to bash scripting and genuinely appreciate the ShellCheck tool!

Comment: ShellCheck **not** SpellCheck ;)